# Хук script_loader_tag WP отключает загрузку других скриптов

Tags: php, wordpress, хук

Wordpress 5.8.
Хочу использовать хук script_loader_tag для изменения атрибутов скрипта загруженного с помощью wp_enqueue_script в футер. Но после добавления строки add_filter("script_loader_tag", "change_my_script", 10, 4) в function.php отключается добавление предыдущих скриптов в футер.
Код в function.php

```
    add_filter("script_loader_tag", "change_my_script", 10, 4);
function change_my_script($tag, $handle, $src, $arg1)
{
    /*   if ("my-script" === $handle) {
        // return str_replace( ' src', ' async src', $tag );
        return str_replace(" src", " defer src", $tag);
    }*/

    return $tag;
}
```

Код на странице:

```
<?php $tag = apply_filters("script_loader_tag", $tag, "modal-form", $src); ?>
```

Мне не понятно почему. В документации и гугле что-то ответа не нашел.
PS. На закомментированные строки просьба внимания не обращать. Это обработчик.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress сам выполняет `apply_filters( 'script_loader_tag', $tag, $handle, $src )`. Вам совершенно не надо этого делать.

Во-вторых, у этого фильтра 3 параметра, а не 4.

`add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'change_my_script', 10, 3 );`

Так вы ничего не сломаете.